# Angular 6 : When i am trying to pass object to dropData it's returning '[Object Object]'

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop

Expected output like log value in constructer but it's giving '[Object Object]'.

Please help me. Minimal reproduction of the problem with instructions You can check in stackblitz link i provided. i got '[Object Object]'.

Check link : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mevcaz

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DropEvent } from 'angular-draggable-droppable';
import { User } from './user';

@Component({
  selector: 'mwl-demo-app',
  templateUrl: './demo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./demo.component.css']
})
export class DemoComponent {
  droppedData: Object = '';
  data: User = {'id': 5};
  constructor() {
    console.log(this.data);
   }
   onDrop(dropData: DropEvent<JSON>): void {

    debugger;
    this.droppedData = dropData;
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.droppedData = '';
    }, 2000);
  }
}
```

Component code:

```
<div mwlDraggable dropData="foo" dragActiveClass="drag-active">
  Drag me!
</div>
<div mwlDraggable dropData="{{data}}" dragActiveClass="drag-active" [dragSnapGrid]="{x: 100, y: 100}">
  I snap to a 100 x 100 grid
</div>
<div
  mwlDroppable
  (drop)="onDrop($event.dropData)"
  dragOverClass="drop-over-active">
  <span [hidden]="droppedData">Drop here</span>
  <span [hidden]="!droppedData">Item dropped here with data: "{{ droppedData }}"!</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Issue

You are trying to pass the value but its not acting @Input. Its just the directive.

### Fix

Add the bracket [] which implies that the attribute is support to be the input for the component.

Change your code as -

```
<div mwlDraggable [dropData]="data" dragActiveClass="drag-active">
  Drag me!
</div>
<div mwlDraggable [dropData]="data" dragActiveClass="drag-active" [dragSnapGrid]="{x: 100, y: 100}">
  I snap to a 100 x 100 grid
</div>
<div
  mwlDroppable
  (drop)="onDrop($event)"
  dragOverClass="drop-over-active">
  <span [hidden]="droppedData">Drop here</span>
  <span [hidden]="!droppedData">Item dropped here with data: "{{ droppedData }}"!</span>
</div>
```

Working copy is here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3fsoyx

Comment: Thank you so much it help's lot.

Answer (score 1):

use for attribute settings square brackets.

So use **[dropData]="data"** instead of **dropData="{{data}}"**

Comment: Thank you so much it help's lot.